# Pass data from controller to assets js in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I am using rails 5.I try to pass the data from controller (which is taken from sql query) to js file in assests.
And I run the query from controller as

```
@sample = Sample.all
```

I need to display data in fullcalendar events.
assets/js file

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaDay,listWeek,agendaWeek,month'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            defaultView: 'listWeek',
            navLinks: true,
            events: [
                <% @sample.each do |sample| %>
                {
                    title: '<%= sample.title %>',
                    start:  TODAY + 'T09:00:00',
                    description: '<%= sample.description %>'
                }
                <% end %>
```

it didn't show the result in fullcalendar. How to pass it from controller to asset/js
Thanks much for quick response

Comment: you say it didn't display...what does the rendered Javascript for the events look like? Does it include a valid array? Show us, if you're not sure. (Check your browser's View Source to see the final output). Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: P.S. did you say you're writing this into a .JS file? I don't know rails, but I would guess it can only write into the view, not into (what is intended to be) a static JS file. Perhaps you need to move this code into your view, and/or use a separate URL endpoint as the source of events (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. will try with json feed. It may pass the data. Let me check now. :+1:

Comment: @Prabha Did you try the gon gem like my example in the below?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use gon gem for this problem, like the below example:

**in controller file:**

> gon.user_id = @user.id

**in js file:**

> console.log(gon.user_id);

" *Gon gem — get your Rails variables in your js. If you need to send some data to your js files and you don't want to do this with long way through views and parsing - use this force!* "

For more info:

https://github.com/gazay/gon

Comment: It's not clear to me how this is relevant to the events not displaying in the calendar. perhaps you can edit the question to explain.

Comment: @ADyson Definitely you are wrong, this answer includes the very helpful example and info. Prabha want to how to pass data to js from controller in rails. Do you know or use gon gem?

Comment: @ADyson Also, I know this gem and this gem is solving this problem.

Comment: Thanks for ur guide @hamdi. I go through with the github link. It shows rabl. I didn't use that before. So I am refering the rabl first and then I'll try with that. Let u know if I have any doubts with this concept. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Prabha You are welcome. I didn't use with rabl, you can use without rabl. If this answer solved this problem, please click the accept button this answer.

Comment: @hamdi I don't use rails, no, I use fullCalendar which is how I found the question. But still even if you're using rails it doesn't give a very clear explanation of how precisely it helps. If there are parts of the external link which explain, you should copy them into here, because links rot - so the answer could be useless in future if the link changes

Comment: @ADyson Yes, I am using Rails. I think this answer is giving a clear explanation for the developers who are using Rails. I used this gem, like in my answer soon. If the link changes, there is nothing I can do. As a result, this link is Github link. I improved the answer a little.

Comment: "If the link changes, there is nothing I can do". Nothing except copy enough information into your answer to allow a reader to understand what the code does and how to use it. The documentation might change location, even if the code still exists somewhere google-able. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer if you think I'm being pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method is to place a partial in **layouts/_variables.html.erb**, then render it in a `<script>` tag in your application layout.

For example:

```
<script>    
  _app.samples = [
  <% @sample.each do |sample| %>
       {
         title: '<%= sample.title %>',
         start:  TODAY + 'T09:00:00',
         description: '<%= sample.description %>'
      }
  <% end %>  
  ];
</script>
```

Then inside your original calendar, just use the generated Javascript directly:

```
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaDay,listWeek,agendaWeek,month'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        defaultView: 'listWeek',
        navLinks: true,
        events: _app.samples,
```

In **layouts/application.html.erb**

```
</script>
  <%= render partial: "layouts/_variables" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  ...
```

It has the benefit that you do not need to pollute you Javascript assets with Rails code, and data is updated on every page refresh without extra round-trips to the server.

The disadvantage is that you need to consider Ajax requests separately (although that is a whole different question), and should take care to place these variables in an app specific structure so as not to pollute your global space with random variables.